# Docker Registry Mirror connected to a private insecure registry

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I am having a private registry (JFrog) which is being used within the company. I would like to set up a registry cache for our project that keeps the heavy load off the private registry.

As the documentation states a registry mirror for private registries is not supported although an answer in [Mirroring private docker registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29900351/mirroring-private-docker-registry) states that now it is supported.

I tried myself with the following setup:

**[UBUNTU CLIENT] --- [REGISTRY PROXY] --- [PRIVATE REGISTRY]**

**Registry Proxy** is reachable at **192.168.178.111:30222 (running in k8s)**

**The private registry** contains an image with the name **myregistry/mypersonalimg:latest**

It is kind of working but not the way I'd like it to. If I want to pull the image from the client I have to use the following command

```
docker pull 192.168.178.111:30222/mypersonalimg:latest
```

I would have expected docker pull myregistry/mypersonalimg:latest would work but I guess docker will look then for a registry called myregistry.

Comment: a curl to the registry http://192.168.178.111:30222/v2/_catalog then prints out {"repositories":["mypersonalimg"]}  :D

Comment: As a workaround, maybe you could just add "192.168.178.111 myregistry"  within your client /etc/hosts. But it's only a workaround!

Answer (score 0):

Setting /etc/docker/daemon.json with registry-mirrors on the client would work for your case. The dockerd on client will attempting the configured mirrors if the pulled image doesn't give repository address.